# Instafeed.js - Sortby most-liked when 60+ images

Tags: javascript, instafeedjs

I am using instafeed.js to display Instagram images on my homepage.

I got 1000+ images I would like to sortby most-liked and load 60 at a time.

When I use "sortBy: most-liked" it looks like instafeed.js loads the 60 recent images and then sort these 60 by most-liked. When I load the next 60 images I get the next 60 recent images and these sorted by most liked.

It looks like it is not posible to sort all 1000+ images by most-liked. And then load 60 at a time?

Is this how instafeed.js works? Or is it a bug?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var feed = new Instafeed({
   sortBy: 'most-liked',
    get: 'tagged',
   tagName: 'awesome',
   clientId: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
  });
 feed.run();
</script>
```

Kind regards

Comment: could you provide some code?

Comment: Hello roeb I am using it as described on the hompage [link](http://instafeedjs.com/)

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    var feed = new Instafeed({
        sortBy: 'most-liked',get: 'tagged',
        tagName: 'awesome',
        clientId: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
    });
    feed.run();
</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, currently instafeed supports to load max of 60 images. But there is a way to load more images and display them as you requested and it need little bit of code work.

for the first you need to follow the following steps;

1. Call feed.next() store the data until it reach 1000 images. - call it from "after" callback of instafeed.
2. Sort the images using like counts - need to have our own compare function.
3. create the template to show the images.
4. Finally slice the data (60 out of 1000) and display in the Div.

```js
var nextButton = document.getElementById('next-feeds');
    var imgs = [];       // store the images for caching
    var images = [];
    var currentPage = 1;

    var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: 'ajith',
        clientId: '467ede5a6b9b48ae8e03f4e2582aeeb3',
        resolution: 'thumbnail',
        limit: 60,
        mock: true,
        template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" class="instagramImg"/></a><label>Liked by <b>{{model.likes.count}}</b> people</label>',
        cachedNext: function () {  // read the cached instagram data
            var nextImages = imgs.slice((currentPage - 1) * feed.options.limit, (currentPage) * feed.options.limit);
            $("#instafeed").html(nextImages);
        },
        after: function () {
            if (images.length < 300)
            {
                feed.next();
            }
            else
            {
                var result;
                images.sort(compare);
                for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                    image = images[i];
                    result = this._makeTemplate(this.options.template, {
                        model: image,
                        id: image.id,
                        link: image.link,
                        image: image.images[this.options.resolution].url,
                        likeCount: image.likes.count
                    });
                    imgs.push(result);
                }
                var imgsPerPage = imgs.slice((currentPage - 1) * feed.options.limit, (currentPage) * feed.options.limit);
                $("#instafeed").html(imgsPerPage);
            }
        },
        success: function (data) {
            images.push.apply(images, data.data);
        }
    });

    feed.run();

    // bind the next button
    nextButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        $("#instafeed").fadeOut(100);
        $("#instafeed").empty();
        $("#instafeed").fadeIn(100);
        currentPage++;

        feed.options.cachedNext();
    });

    function compare(a, b) {
        // alert(a.likes.count);
        if (a.likes.count < b.likes.count)
            return -1;
        if (a.likes.count > b.likes.count)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="http://sriajith.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/instafeed.min_.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="instaFeedButton">
<button id="next-feeds" class="btn-feed">Next</button>
</div>
<br/> <br/>                
<div id="instafeed" class="instagramFeed"></div>
```

If you want to add the pagination, you can find some info here [here](http://sriajith.info/blog/displaying-instagram-feeds-on-website-with-pagination/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am going to accept it. I just want to hear your opinion about these quotes from Instgram Developer Documentation in relation to creating a solution like above. 1) Do not abuse the API. Too many requests too quickly will get your access turned off 2) Max request 5,000 / hour per application